# react value catching issue

Tags: reactjs, react-props

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1kOx.jpg)features2.b' is missing in props validation prop-types [code[mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzefr.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQePo.jpg)

why this error occurring[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUpDY.jpg)
please suggest what can I do changes for this code.
Tried everything but not happening.
what changes required?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTyDc.jpg)

Comment: Did you look at what you've posted? it's a mess of text and image links randomly in it. Also, please don't ever take pictures of the screen of your code with a camera. Don't even take screenshots of code. Re-format your question completely, explain what your issue is, what you have tried to do to solve it, and include your code as text, formatted as code.